# Is there a class build in .NET environment which inherits from MarshalByRefObject?

Tags: c#, .net

The question is in the title.

I am looking for some class which could be used to configure the remoting as an endpoint for the client.

Thanks

Comment: "inherits from MarshalByRefObject", how would that allow you to configure remoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx#inheritanceContinued

I do not understand why you cannot create your own class for the specific remoting scenario.

Comment: To be able to use the common class in client and server so that the client didn't need to reference another user assembly. I am trying to establish a remoting so that only one executable could be published.